# How to find an average for dictionary in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary, let's say

```
let gamePrices = [
"Shooter": [40,60,80],
"RTS": [15,35,55]
"RPG": [5,40,70]
]
avgGamePrices(dictionary: [String: Int]) -> Double {
var total = 0;
for int in dictionary {
total += int
}
```

(i suppose, using of int is wrong here)
And i don't understand how to get each genre avg price, and total avg price (of all 9 values). I don't even know how to get total here, how should i "mention" the ints or strings of a dictionary in for loop?
For default array i'd use

```
for number in numbers {
total += number
}
let numbersTotal = Int(numbers.count);
let average = total/numbersTotal;
return (Double(average);
```

Comment: Can you have less Shooters values the RTS?

Comment: I'm afraid no, here i wrote my own new code. but first of all I need to make complete my assignment, and there are the same number of ints for strings ( as in my example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the average of all prices you need to first get all prices from your dictionary then you can calculate the average. It is not the same as calculating the average of the averages:

```
let gamePrices = [
    "Shooter": [40,60,80],
    "RTS":     [15,35,55],
    "RPG":     [5,40,70]]

let allPrices = gamePrices.flatMap(\.value)
let sum = allPrices.reduce(.zero, +)
let average = Double(sum) / Double(allPrices.count)  //  44.44444444444444
```

To get the maximum price for each genre:

```
let maxPrices: [(genre: String, maxPrice: Int)] = gamePrices.map { ($0, $1.max() ?? .zero)}  // [(genre "Shooter", maxPrice 80), (genre "RTS", maxPrice 55), (genre "RPG", maxPrice 70)]

for (genre, max) in maxPrices {
    print("Genre:", genre, "Max price:", max)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that maxPrices actually works, but it prints a lot of "trash" to the console, is there any easier way without map, ??, and .zero?

Comment: If you are sure the prices array is not empty you can force unwrap its value or leave the result as optional

Comment: Okay, can you then, explain what is it and how it works "gamePrices.map { ($0, $1.max() ?? .zero)}" . I've never used anything like that, with ??, .zero and $ signs, so i don't really understand what is this

Comment: Ok $0 is the first element of the tuple, $1 is the second. A dictionary is a collection where its element is a KeyValue pair defined as `public typealias Element = (key: Key, value: Value)`. So I am mapping each key value pair. $0 is the key while $1 is the value (which is a collection). max is a method of the collection which returns the maximum value from it or nil if the collection is empty

Comment: Note that it can also be written as `gamePrices.map { ($0.key, $0.value.max() ?? .zero)}` which is easier for beginners to understand and used to be the only way to accomplish it before Swift 3 (AFAIR)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I agree that it was not part of the question but I would take me less than 30s to add it to the post. Considering that I had already the code in front of me I decided to post it as well. At least OP showed some effort trying to solve the original question.

Answer (score 1):

If you search a total AVG, so something like this:

```
func avgGamePrices(dictionary: [String: [Int]]) -> Double {
var total = 0;
var countElem = 0

for obj in dictionary {
    countElem += obj.value.count
    for v in obj.value {
        total += v
    }
}

return Double(total / countElem)
```

}

calling:

```
avgGamePrices(dictionary: gamePrices)
```

otherwise for each key:

```
func avg(for key: String, dictionary: [String: [Int]]) -> Double {
var total = 0;
let countElem = (dictionary[key] ?? []).count

for v in (dictionary[key] ?? []) {
    total += v
}

return Double(total / countElem)
```

}

and you can call in this way (passing a single key of your dictionary like a param):

```
avg(for: "RTS", dictionary: gamePrices)
```

Comment: That should work, thank you, but how i count avg for int and total avg in this case?

Comment: And i don't really understand how do i call this function... 
```
print(avgGamePrices(dictionary : gamePrices));
```
that doesn't seem right

Comment: thanks, that is working, nevertheless i already did it without func, with for loop and print( where i did such calculation "total / Double(price.count)"). The last thing left for me to do - to get the max price of each genre. Could you please, if not difficult, tell me where the error is? I assume, it can be done with single line of code.
let maxPrice = gamePrices.max {a,b in a.value < b.value}
print(maxPrice)
But, it says "Binary operator "<" cannot be applied to two '[Int]' operands. That sounds weird...

Comment: Note that it's a bit pointless to first do an integer division and then convert it to a Double, the precision is already lost then, so it's better to first convert the values to Double before  doing the division.

Comment: You should use [Dictionary Key-based subscript with default value](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894528-subscript) which returns a NON optional value `dictionary[key, default: []]`